# How to get exact match of what a user types in an input filed to what's in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, include, indexof

When a user types in a number in the search field, an image with that number populates an image wheel. When a user types in 49, the image with the number 49 should appear.  Instead, the current code gets me all images with the number 4 and all images with the number 9 (like 14, 19, 244, 596, etc) instead of returning one image #49.  filter() did not work, includes() did not work, indexOf() did not work. How to get the one image that corresponds to the input number?

```
function searchInspired() {
        $(".treatment").each(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('searched');
        });

        var searchNum = document.getElementById('searchField').value; //user input

          //treatments is an array of images declared globally
            for (var i=0; i<treatments.length; i++){
                if (treatments[i].number.toString().indexOf(searchNum) !== -1){
                    console.log(treatments[i]); 
                    treatments[i].$elem.addClass('searched');
                }
            }

            $('.treatment').each(function(index, el){
                if(!$(el).hasClass('searched')){

                    $(el).hide();
                }   
                else{
                    $(el).show();
                }        
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: That sounds peculiar. `treatments[i].number.toString().indexOf(searchNum) !== -1` should only include results where `searchNum` (eg `49`) appears as an exact substring somewhere in `treatments[i].number`. Can you make a Stack Snippet illustrating the problem, so we can have a [MCVE] to debug?

Comment: Why couldn't you just use `treatments[i].number.toString() == searchNum`?

Comment: Yes, I get 49 and all the other numbers that have a 9 or 4 in it.  How do I do a Stack Snippet and what do you need to see?

Comment: E,g https://jsfiddle.net copy your code (HTML, JS and if necessary CSS), save and post the link.

Comment: Ok, will you be able to reproduce it since it's all database driven?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link. Code in question is under Search https://jsfiddle.net/hartfib/71kft5mu/3/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The class resetting code might not be working, causing your issue with the "4" of "49" always being shown.  I would try making your reset function look more like your show/hide function.

```
$('.treatment').each(function(index, el){
  $(el).removeClass('searched');
})
```

---

Your matching checks to see if the character they typed appears anywhere in the image number `'149'.indexOf('49')` passes your check.  There are a lot ways you could force this to match exactly, I recommend leaving both as a number and just doing `searchNum === treatments[i].number`.

Possible example:

```
var searchNum = Number(document.getElementById('searchField').value);
if(isNaN(searchNum)) {
  return;               //bad input, don't show any images
}
```

Then your check for the matching image can simply be:

```
 if (treatments[i].number === searchNum) {
   ...add the class...
 }
```

Comment: My issue I've been running into the last two days is when I do treatments[i].number, I get an error back saying "number is not a function" so turning it into a string has worked.

Comment: Actually I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: treatments[i] is undefined".  That's what I've been getting when I do treatments.number

Comment: Hmm that sounds strange, I wonder if turning it to a string is hiding a deeper issue.  If you check out the number prop using something like console.log(treatments.map(x=> x.number)), does it look like you would expect?

Comment: Also weird, do you get those errors when running the code in your question?

Comment: When doing console.log(treatments.map(x=> x.number)), it shows me 774 number (which is correct)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I was able to solve it. A simple break; was all that was needed

Answer (score 0):

You can filter treatments array and then map to

```
treatments.filter(function(treatment){
    return treatment.number.toString() === searchNum.toString()
}).each(function(treatment){
    treatment.$elem.addClass('searched');
});



$(".treatment").not(".searched").show();
$(".treatment.searched").hide();
```

Comment: This is frustrating.  I get this error "Uncaught TypeError: treatments.filter(...).each is not a function"   I wondering is it's something farther up in the code but I'm just not finding it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  I was able to solve it. What I originally had worked but it would keep looping. What I did was add a break; and now works great!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this. My original code worked when adding a break so it would no longer loop and give me exact match

```
for (var i=0; i<treatments.length; i++){
    if (treatments[i].number.toString().indexOf(searchNum) !== -1){
        treatments[i].$elem.addClass('searched');
        break;              
    }
}
```